# set and get data from service Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make parent components communicate to child components by injecting directly the providers in the ts file of each child component for that I want to get a data using the get & set but I do not understand how to do ?

**service**

```
export class ProductSharingDataService {

  public productName!:any;

  constructor() { }

  setRowName(selectedTableRowData:any){
    this.productName = selectedTableRowData;
  }

  getRowName():string{
    return this.productName;
  }

}
```

**components.ts**

```
    @Component({
          selector: 'app-product-page',
          templateUrl: './product-page.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./product-page.component.css'],
          providers: [ProductSharingDataService] // injected service here
        })
        export class ProductPageComponent {
        
          public selectedArrayParent!: Product;
        
          constructor(private productSharingDataService: 
                      ProductSharingDataService) {
            this.productSharingDataService.getRowName();  
            }
        
          receive($event: any) {
            this.selectedArrayParent = $event 
// I need to retrieve this data ( $event ) 
          }
        
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, at least, 2 ways to communicate component parent <-> child:

*NOTE: Instead of 'any', you have to put the appropriate type always*

**1) Using a service as ´store´:**

***service***
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service

```
export class ProductSharingDataService {

  private _productName!:any;

  set rowName(selectedTableRowData:any){
    this._productName = selectedTableRowData;
  }

  get rowName():string{
    return this._productName;
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

***parent***

```
  constructor(private productSharingDataService: ProductSharingDataService) {
     this.productSharingDataService.rowName = 'Info (object, string, whatever...) you want to pass to child';  
  }
```

***child***

```
name: any;

  constructor(private productSharingDataService: ProductSharingDataService) {
     this.name = this.productSharingDataService.rowName;
  }
```

**2) With @input() and @output:**
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

***- In component child:***

```
import { ..., EventEmitter, ..., Output } from '@angular/core';
...


 @Component({
      selector: 'app-child', ....



   @Input() varNameIn: any[] = []; 
    @Output() varNameOut: EventEmitter<any> 
      = new EventEmitter();
    ...
```

When you want to pass something to the parent:

```
const infoToParent:any = 'Info (object, string, whatever...) you want to pass to parent';
this.varNameOut.emit(info);
```

***- In component parent:***

*HTML:*

```
...
<app-child [varNameIn]="infoToChild" (varNameOut)="parentMethodToUseVarNameOutContent($event)"></app-child>
....
```

*TS:*

```
    ...

    // Instead of 'any', you have to put the same type of varNameOut in the child:
    ...
    const infoToChild="Info (object, string, whatever...) you want to pass to child";
    ...
    parentMethodToUseVarNameOutContent(varNameOut: any){
       console.log(varNameOut);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for help, my question how to get row data in parent component in first way ? i have receive method juste above can i do something with ?

Comment: @toto, I guess that you're mixing both ways: When you use services, you don't need pass anything through $event. Try this: 1) Read products not in the parent, but in the service itself (if you can't do that, pass the products from parent to service through a method in the service that take these products and store it in a local variable in the service). 2) The child directly use a method of the service to read this products stored in the service. I hope this help! (sorry, but it's difficult to explain better). A piece of advice: Read all the official Angular info of links I put in the answer

Answer (score 0):

With `@input() and @output` decorator you can also achieve data from one component to another. However, following approach uses `@output` decorator and hope it might solve your problem.

In the receiver component (let's say `ProductPageParentComponent`) typescript, you have to create a method to receive the value of the `productName` variable like this:

```
export class ProductPageParentComponent{

constructor() { }

productName: string;

receiveStringValue($event) {
  this.productName= $event;
 }
}
```

In the receiver component html put the following:

```
<app-product-child-page (stringValueEvent)="receiveStringValue($event)"></app-product-child-page>
<h1>{{productName}}<h1>
```

In the sender component (let's say `ProductPageChildComponent`) typescript (`app-product-child-page` selector), you should declare a `stringValueEvent` variable with the `@Output()` decorator and set it equal to a new event emitter.

```
export class ProductPageChildComponent{

  productName: string;

  @Output() stringValueEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productName= "Sample Product";
    this.stringValueEvent.emit(this.productName);
  }
}
```